# Vuetify v-btn with external link and dynamic property

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a button on my app that will open a vnc tunnel. The url is vnc://xxxxxxx:portnumber

The :portnumber is a dynamically generated property coming from a database called using Axios. I am trying to write this code as follows, but clearly missing something.

```
<v-btn href="vnc://hostname:{{computer.Port}}">
  VNC
</v-btn>
```

How do I write the statement for the href attribute correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your input. My actual solution is below.

```
<v-btn class="ma-2" tile outlined color="success" :href="`${getVNCPort()}`">
            <v-icon left>mdi-remote-desktop</v-icon>VNC
          </v-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `:href` instead of `href` to bind a javascript attribute

```
<v-btn :href="'vnc://hostname:' + computer.Port">
  VNC
</v-btn>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. My actual solution is below.
```
<v-btn class="ma-2" tile outlined color="success" :href="`${getVNCPort()}`">
            <v-icon left>mdi-remote-desktop</v-icon>VNC
          </v-btn>
```